# how to create Super Table field programmatically

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-supertable

i am trying to create a super table field programmatically.
this is the code i tried.

i see super table field in field list but i can see fields inside of super table.

how can i do this?

```
    //create super table field itself
    $superTable = new SuperTableField([
        'name' => 'supertablefield',
        'handle' => 'supertablefield',
        'groupId' => 1
    ]);
    Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($superTable);
    //field inside super table
    $field = new \craft\fields\PlainText([
        "name" => 'textfield',
        "handle" => 'textfield',
        "translationMethod" => "site",
        "multiline" => 0,
    ]);
   //create and set block type
    $blockModel = new SuperTableBlockTypeModel();
    $blockModel->fieldId = $superTable->id;
    $blockModel->uid = StringHelper::UUID();
    $blockModel->setFields([$field]);

    $superTable->setBlockTypes([$blockModel]);
    SuperTable::$plugin->service->saveBlockType($blockModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the answer without playing, but try saving the plain text field before adding it to the super table:

```
    // Create the super table field

    $superTable = new SuperTableField([
        'name' => 'supertablefield',
        'handle' => 'supertablefield',
        'groupId' => 1
    ]);

    Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($superTable);


    // Create plain text field

    $field = new \craft\fields\PlainText([
        "name" => 'textfield',
        "handle" => 'textfield',
        "translationMethod" => "site",
        "multiline" => 0,
    ]);


    // Save the plain text field

    Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($field);


    // Retrieve the plain text field 

    $plainTextField = Craft::$app->fields->getFieldByHandle("textfield")


    // Create and set the block

    $blockModel = new SuperTableBlockTypeModel();
    $blockModel->fieldId = $superTable->id;
    $blockModel->uid = StringHelper::UUID();
    $blockModel->setFields([$plainTextField]);
    $superTable->setBlockTypes([$blockModel]);
    SuperTable::$plugin->service->saveBlockType($blockModel);
```

Comment: Not sure if you could do `$plainTextField = Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($field)` to make it cleaner.

Comment: thanks! it works. i don't know why but when i create matrix there is no need to save field before setting field in block type -although this is another topic-